# I have VS 2013 with Update 2... How to delete a folder. I'm a visual learning so please try to simplify your answers

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I've inherited TFS and VS 2013 with Update 2 from someone who went on leave for 1 year. Shortly after I was asked to delete a folder. this was 3 months ago and now one eye keeps twitching haha. Please simplify any answers due to I'm a visual learner.
Is the process worth the headache?

Comment: Have you looked at any documentation? What steps have you tried? Where are you encountering problems?

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is as below:

1. In either Solution Explorer or Source Control Explorer, browse to the folder or file that you want to delete.
2. Select the items that you want to delete, open their context menu (right-click), and choose **Delete**.

   [image]
3. When you are ready, check in your changes.

> Note: If the file was checked in to version control before the delete,
>   then you can recover the file.

Check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/delete-restore-files-folders

> Or you can use [Delete Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/delete-command-team-foundation-version-control) to remove files and folders from
>   the Team Foundation version control server and deletes them from the
>   disk.
>
> If you want to destroy, or permanently delete, version-controlled
>   files from Team Foundation version control, use [Destroy Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control).